# Error deserializing ConcurrentHashMap: Possible JVM bug

Tags: java, serialization, jvm

We have a serializable class containing a ConcurrentHashMap field. Almost all the times the serialization/deserialization of this class works perfectly.
However, we just received a file containing a serialized version of this class and when we try to deserialize it, we are getting an error msg like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:417)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:883)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.readObject(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1278)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:974)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
```

Could this be a JVM bug? The error occurs entirely inside jvm classes.

Comment: how would that explain the lock object not being created. corrupted data would be the contents of the hash map, not itself.

Comment: anyway I think only this information is not enough to conclude anything. Have tried deserializing same file on different PCs and JREs?

Comment: also the 'sync' object which in throwing the NPE inside the ReentrantLock doesnt even have a state

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov we have. same result.

Comment: I think you need to share code how you serialize and deserialize and the file itself.

Comment: Its pretty obvious we are calling ObjectOutputStream.readObject(). As i have said, this piece of code has worked very well so far, just not in this particular case.

Comment: is it only one single file that fails or the exception is reproducible?

Comment: not reproducible in any other file so far.

Comment: do you know exact jvm version where the file has been created?

Comment: do you serialize the ConcurrentHashMap while it is still possibly being modified?

Comment: @jtahlborn nope. again none of that should have any effect. if you look at the source of the error, its on an object that has no serializable state.

Comment: if you suspect a jvm bug, I would try to latest update e.g. java 6 update 37 or java 7 update 10 to see if it has already been fixed.

Comment: not sure what you mean by "no serializable state"?  the ReentrantLock class has a `sync` member variable (which seems to be null), all of which is Serializable.